# Parse a long string using gsub and replacement is reserved char in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a character vector of the form (below). When you read this vector it is one long string such as, `"tBodyAcc-XYZ\tGravityAcc-XYZ\tBodyAccJerk-XYZ\BodyGyro-XYZ..."` where whitespace is split by the escape char "\".

How can I use gsub to replace the white space pattern = " ", replacement = " ", so that each variable name is surrounding by quotes and is an element of the vector?

Ideally, I'd be able to say varnames[1] and get back "tBodyAacc-XYZ".

Thank you for your time on this matter.

```
varnames <- "tBodyAcc-XYZ
    tGravityAcc-XYZ
    tBodyAccJerk-XYZ
    tBodyGyro-XYZ
    tBodyGyroJerk-XYZ
    tBodyAccMag
    ..."
```

Comment: Sick. That totally worked. I love Stack and R. So many solutions available.

Comment: The `\t` sequence is the escape for the tab character. Or are you saying the "t" is supposed to be part of the variable name?

Comment: "t" is part of the varName. Thanks @MrFlick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
scan(text=gsub('\\s+', ' ', varnames), sep='', what='')
```